# MaaS KVM node - Failed Deployment - df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems

Tags: virtualization, maas, kvm-virtualization

I am able to commission the kvm node, but when I try to deploy it fails.
Last output from failed nodes cloud-init-output.log is:

`df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory`

I use Virt Install to create the kvm:

```
sudo virt-install --name=maas-node-1 --connect=qemu:///system --ram=4096 
--vcpus=2 --hvm --virt-type=qemu --pxe --boot network,hd 
--os-variant=ubuntutrusty --graphics vnc --noautoconsole 
--os-type=linux --accelerate --disk=/var/kvm/images/maas-node-1.qcow2,size=80,bus=ide,format=qcow2,cache=none,sparse=true, 
--network=bridge=br0
```

Power Management is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it didn't like the `--virt-type=qemu` changing from qemu to kvm solved my problems.